# Sorting an array in descending order using visual basic in VS2012

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm making a program that is randomly generating numbers into 100 rows of 15 in a ListBox using a button click. I need to get it sorted from LARGEST to SMALLEST, from left to right across the rows. I have a bubble sort in place but it is sorting smallest to largest and only down the first column.

This is how I am getting the numbers generated:

```
 Private Sub btnGen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGen.Click
    'Number Generator
    Dim rn As New Random()
    Dim array(14) As Integer      
    Dim temp As Integer
    Dim st As String

    For y As Integer = 1 To 100
        For x As Integer = 1 To 15
            array(x - 1) = rn.Next(100, 1000)
        Next
        txtList.Items.Add(ats(array))
    Next
    st = st & vbNewLine

    Call sort()

    Using fs As New FileStream(My.Settings.DAT_PATH, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)
        Using sw As New StreamWriter(fs)
            sw.WriteLine()
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub

Function ats(ar As Integer()) As String
    'FUNCTION for array to string seperated by comma
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    For x As Integer = 0 To UBound(ar)
        If x = UBound(ar) Then
            sb.Append(ar(x).ToString)
        Else
            sb.Append(ar(x).ToString & ", ")
        End If
    Next
    Return sb.ToString
End Function
```

This is how I am sorting them:

```
 Sub sort()

    'bubble sort from biggest to smallest 
    txtList.Sorted = True
    Dim array(14) As Integer
    Dim temp As Integer
    For ipass = 1 To UBound(array)
        For i = 0 To UBound(array) - 1
            If array(i) > array(i + 1) Then
                temp = array(i)
                array(i) = array(i + 1)
                array(i + 1) = temp
                array.Reverse()
            End If
        Next i
    Next ipass
End Sub
```

Lastly, here is an example of my current results:

107, 512, 139, 233, 582, 460, 698, 231, 395, 724, 717, 284, 699, 419, 825

119, 214, 513, 382, 538, 161, 431, 603, 573, 354, 757, 307, 204, 906, 200

124, 493, 153, 507, 675, 878, 698, 911, 625, 171, 915, 174, 270, 629, 770

126, 585, 480, 317, 731, 193, 385, 143, 152, 374, 246, 124, 205, 347, 936

139, 497, 422, 381, 127, 968, 236, 637, 406, 758, 594, 944, 929, 733, 428

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is the intended purpose of `array.Reverse()` in there?

Comment: I was trying to get it to reverse the sort. Meant to take that out since it did absolutely nothing to change the outcome.

Comment: The `array` in `Sub btnGen_Click` is not the same variable as `array` in `Sort()`. What you should do is pass `array` as a parameter to the `Sort()` method. [Wikipedia: Scope (computer science)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)) is relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an alternative solution using a dedicated class.

The `Input()` method accepts a boolean switch that allows to sort the `List(Of Integer)` by Ascending or Descending order.
The `Output()` method will return a `String()` array that can be passed to a `ListBox`, using its `.AddRange()` method.
The `Delimiter` property can be used to specify how the string components (the integer values in this case) must be separated.

```
Private Class SortedLists
    Private OutputList As List(Of String)

    Public Sub New()
        OutputList = New List(Of String)
        Delimiter = ", "
    End Sub

    Public Property Delimiter As String

    Public Sub Input(Values As List(Of Integer), Ascending As Boolean)
        If Ascending Then
            Values.Sort()
        Else
            Dim IValues As IOrderedEnumerable(Of Integer) = Values.OrderByDescending(Function(i) i)
            Values = IValues.ToList()
        End If

        OutputList.Add(String.Join("", Values.
                              Select(Function(val, i) (val.ToString &
                              If(i < Values.Count - 1, Delimiter, "")))))
    End Sub

    Public Function Output() As String()
        Return OutputList.ToArray()
    End Function
End Class
```

The refactored procedure creates the random integers list, add the string results to a `ListBox` control, saves the strings to a file.
The elapsed time for the whole procedure, calculated with a `StopWatch`,  is 7~9 milliseconds.
Using [`File.WriteAllLines()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealllines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) the elapsed time is 10~14 milliseconds.

```
Dim rn As New Random()
Dim MySortedLists As New SortedLists
Dim MyIntegerList As New List(Of Integer)

For y As Integer = 1 To 100
    For x As Integer = 1 To 15
        MyIntegerList.Add(rn.Next(100, 1000))
    Next
    MySortedLists.Input(MyIntegerList, False)
    MyIntegerList.Clear()
Next

txtList.Items.AddRange(MySortedLists.Output())

'File.WriteAllLines is a little slower, but it's easier to read
File.WriteAllLines(My.Settings.DAT_PATH, MySortedLists.Output)


'Using fs As New FileStream(My.Settings.DAT_PATH, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)
'    Using sw As New StreamWriter(fs)
'        For Each line As String In MySortedLists.Output
'            sw.WriteLine(line)
'        Next
'    End Using
'End Using
```

Comment: This way works perfectly for what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I followed your "way" of doing things. You should know there are way better ways to achieve what you want.

```
Private Sub btnGen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGen.Click
    'Number Generator
    Dim rn As New Random()
    Dim array(14) As Integer
    Dim temp As Integer
    Dim st As String

    For y As Integer = 1 To 100
        For x As Integer = 1 To 15
            array(x - 1) = rn.Next(100, 1000)
        Next
        'txtList.Items.Add(ats(array))
    Next

    Dim sortedArray = sort(array)



    Using fs As New FileStream(My.Settings.DAT_PATH, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)
        Using sw As New StreamWriter(fs)
            For Each item In sortedArray
                sw.WriteLine(item)
            Next
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub

Function sort(array() As Integer) As IEnumerable(Of Integer)

    'bubble sort from biggest to smallest 
    txtList.Sorted = True

    Dim temp As Integer
    For ipass = 1 To UBound(array)
        For i = 0 To UBound(array) - 1
            If array(i) > array(i + 1) Then
                temp = array(i)
                array(i) = array(i + 1)
                array(i + 1) = temp

            End If
        Next i
    Next ipass
    Dim sortedArray = array.Reverse()
    Return sortedArray
End Function
```

Comment: I am trying it with your modifications. When I comment out this line, 'txtList.Items.Add(ats(array)), the listbox shows up blank upon button click. If I uncomment it I am back to square one with the sort order. I am sure there are better ways to do this but I am very new to programming and learning.

Comment: Why the `array.Reverse()` instead of simply reversing the comparison in the bubble sort?